# Safari (and Chrome Mobile) z-index issue with rotateY

Tags: html, css, safari, transform

https://jsfiddle.net/nxbg7rq3/

In this example I need the .mask to be completely on top of the .screen. In Safari (and Chrome Mobile) that just doesn't want to work. I've tried a lot and am at the end of my tether.

It'd be nice to accomplish this without me having to change a lot of the structure that's already present in the jfiddle. Ta!

html

```
  <div class="device">

    <div class="perspective">

      <div class="screen">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="mask"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
 .container {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.device {
     -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-38%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
    transform: translate3d(-38%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.perspective {
  perspective: 114.35897435897436em;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
  width: auto
}

.screen {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 67.5% 50%;
    transform-origin: 67.5% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-51%) scale(1.07) rotateY(34deg);
    transform: translateY(-51%) scale(1.07) rotateY(34deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2.5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 5px solid #fa5d86;
    z-index: 0;
}

.screen img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.mask {
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
  transform-style: flat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double .mask? Example:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="device">
    <div class="mask" style="position: absolute;"></div>
    <div class="perspective">

      <div class="screen">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="mask" style="opacity: 0;"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's not really an option, since the mask is an image in the actual use-case and the page will be heavy enough as it is. It actually works though, so it would be a good last straw solution!

Comment: transform: translateY(-51%) scale(1.07) rotateY(34deg);  this problem due to rotateY(34deg)

maybe can do through css-hak another design for safari

Comment: I realise the problem stems from the rotateY. Another way to display it for Safari isn't really what I had in mind. If there's no other way, sure. But hopefully there's some solution for it.